# Detect HTML5 usage

Tags: website, html5

Is it possible to check if a website uses HTML5 elements (and which ones)?

For example I know Youtube uses the `<video>` element, but does it use some other elements as well?

I've tried reading the source to spot new elements but it's a hard task.

(I posted this on Super User because it's not really programming related. More a use of websites that do this (like validators) or plugins.)

Comment: updated my question

Comment: @PoweRoy: Within Firefox (and any other modern browser) you can use `Ctrl+F` in the source view...should speed things a little up.

Comment: Ctrl+F is not handy because of the use of Javascripts. So I got to keep up looking for javascript includes

Answer (score 6):

If you want to see if a website is using HTML5 elements, you only need to view the source of the website.

If the source code starts with the following declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

you're onto a HTML5 marked up website.

Also, it may be using some [new elements introduced](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-html5/):

```
<article>
<aside>
<audio>
<canvas>
<command>
<datagrid>
<details>
<dialog>
<figure>
<footer>
<header>
<m>
<meter>
<nav>
<output>
<progress>
<section>
<source>
<time>
<video>
```

Here's a peek at the source code on a Youtube page running the `<video>` element:

[image: youtube html5 source code]

Seen through the **Inspect element** right-click option in Google Chrome, you'll note the declaration at the top is `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` specifying the use of HTML5 elements on the page.

Comment: doctype is not completely usefull because youtube has <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" on the HTML5 document.

Comment: Show an example Youtube page that uses the `<video>` tag. @pow

Comment: go with e.g. chrome (due h.264 usage) to http://www.youtube.com/html5, click on join the beta. And then watch any video on youtube. It will show the video in the <video> element

Comment: You're right about the source code when you switch Youtube over to HTML5 version. @pow

Comment: Judging from Ctrl+F-ing the youtube page I think the only HTML5 element used is <video>. If I disable the HTML5 player and use flash on youtube, the '<!DOCTYPE HTML>' is still set (viewing the source code it is something else(see first comment)). The doctype is only used by the browser for rendering purposes, therefore doctype is reliable: http://themaingate.net/dev/html/all-you-need-is-doctype-html

Comment: Sites currently making use of HTML5 are also using fallbacks for when elements are available/showing to certain users. @pow